# Get entry from one form field and search for its corresponding data in database and auto fill other fields in form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am writing a code for billing, here inside it rather to enter every entry by typing i wanted to do something like if record already exist then, enter one field other corresponding fields will automatically be filled with corresponding data. For eg: inside my form there is a section to display customer info and that is done by entering customer_id then a PHP file fetches name address phone number and other data corresponding to the entered customer_id and auto fill other customer fields of form.
HTML form

```
<form action="./manipulate/invoice.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div style="width:15%;float:left">
Customer #
<br>
<input id="searchbox" style="width:98%;margin-left:1%;margin:right:1%" name="cust_id" type="text" placeholder="Customer ID">
</div>
<div class="w3-container">
<div style="width:100%;">
<h4>Contact Info About Customer</h4>

</div>

<div style="width:30%;float:left" >
<input id="cust_address" style="width:98%;margin-left:1%;margin:right:1%" type="text" placeholder="Customer_Address" >
</div>

<div style="width:15%;float:left">
<input style="width:98%;margin-left:1%;margin:right:1%" type="text" placeholder="City" id="cust_city">
</div>

<div style="width:15%;float:left">
<input style="width:98%;margin-left:1%;margin:right:1%" type="text" placeholder="State" id="cust_state">
</div>

<div style="width:15%;float:left">
<input style="width:98%;margin-left:1%;margin:right:1%" type="number" placeholder="Pincode" id="cust_pincode">
</div>

<div style="width:25%;float:left">
<input style="width:98%;margin-left:1%;margin:right:1%" type="number" placeholder="Phone Number"  id="cust_phone">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function trial(s){
        $('#searchbox').val(s);
        $.ajax({
            url:'./manipulate/get_addre.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:'cust_id='+s,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(e){
                //$('#cust_add').append(e['address']);
                $('#cust_Address').val(e['address']);
                $('#cust_city').val(e['city']);
                $('#cust_state').val(e['state']);
                $('#cust_pincode').val(e['pincode']);
                $('#cust_phone').val(e['phone']);
                $('#cust_Name').val(e['name']);
                }

        });
    }
  });
$('#searchbox').change(function() {
    trail($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

get_addre.php is

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","tssolutions");

if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo "connection failed : $mysqli->connect_errno";
    exit();
}
$cust_id = $_POST['cust_name'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerid = '".$cust_id."' ";
//echo 'hi';
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    /* fetch details*/
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $json = json_encode($row);
        //return $json;
        echo $json;
        //echo "<b>Address : </b>".$row['address'].", ".$row['city'].", ".$row['state'].", ".$row['pincode'].", contact no. ".$row['phone'];
    }
    $result->free();
}
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

And in invoice.php these fields + some more fields are being inserted into another table in database.
The problem i am facing is whenever i enter into customer_id field in form rest all fields remains blank which were supposed to auto fill..
Anyone can correct it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing i have to say is: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should change this line:

```
$cust_id = $_POST['cust_name'];
```

to this line:

```
$cust_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['cust_name']);
```

On the first glance i do not see any error, but oddly there is no event handler, that will acutally call your JavaScript trial function. It seems like you are missing this part of the code:

```
$('#searchbox').change(function() {
    trial($(this).val());
});
```

**Edit**
After rebuilding your application i have found your error. You are sending data with the name 'cust_id' but you are requesting data with the name 'cust_name'. Once you change your names to the correct one, this will work.

You can use the web developer consoles (F12 in Chrome and Firefox) to have a look at the server response to your ajax calls in the newtwork tab.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion of SQL Injection. Also i did add the following code still it result same, all other fields are still null, they ain't get values .

Comment: Your eventhandler has to be inside your $(document).ready() function. I also made a typo and spelled your function wrong (shame on me). Besides that i have found your error and edited my answer.

Comment: oh god, such a little mistake (shame on me), actually i wrote the code about 1 years back but someone wanted me to modify if and changed the code after 1 year hence miss-spelled the variables (my bad)...